# Find combinations from Arrays

Tags: php, combinations, permutation

```
$array1=["joe","bob"];
$array2=["tom","bill"];
$array3=["dan","mary"];
```

I want to print out every combination.. like (joe,tom,dan),( joe,tom,mary), only picking 1 from each array for each combination. and so on until there are no more combinations.  After this i want to post them onto 3 post forms on my website.. I know how to do that but I am stuck on this combination part.

Hard to explain.. hope you have understood..

Comment: Is repetition is allowed. ?

Comment: Yes.. I believe permutations would be the correct term for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 for loops:

```
$combinations = new ArrayObject();
foreach ($array1 as $name1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $name2) {
        foreach ($array3 as $name3) {
            $combinations->append(array($name1, $name2, $name3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: var_dump($combinations); It gives me a big mesh (http://gyazo.com/459a17ed0e456ec598e6fb3cb65cd77d). Any way I could echo it as an array per combination since I am trying to Post each array with cURL?

Comment: It's an array of arrays. Each array is a combination [name1, name2, name3]. It's already an array per combination: `$combinations[0]` it's the first combination, `$combinations[1]` the second one etc.
You can print it "well" for example using `foreach ($combinations as $c) { print join($c, ", ") . "\n"; }`

Comment: YOU are a life saver. Could you explain append()? I don't understand the php.net's explanation

Comment: It just adds the element at the end. It's the same as `$combinations[] = new_element` ; it's just that I come from python where this syntax doesn't exist, while `append()` is used a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

When no reputation is not allowed

```
<?php

$array1=["joe","bob"];
$array2=["tom","bill"];
$array3=["dan","mary"];

$arr = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3);
$result = array();

function noRepeatation($arr, $temp_string, &$collect) {
    if ($temp_string != "") 
        $collect []= $temp_string;

    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr);$i++) {
        $arrcopy = $arr;
        $elem = array_splice($arrcopy, $i, 1); // removes and returns the i'th element
        if (sizeof($arrcopy) > 0) {
            noRepeatation($arrcopy, $temp_string ." " . $elem[0], $collect);
        } else {
            $collect []= $temp_string. " " . $elem[0];
        }   
    }   
}

$collect = array();
noRepeatation($arr, "", $collect);
print_r($collect);
?>
```

When reputation is allowed

```
<?php
$array1=["joe","bob"];
$array2=["tom","bill"];
$array3=["dan","mary"];

$arr = array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3);
$result = array();

function repeatation($arr, $level, &$result, $curr=array()) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        $new = array_merge($curr, array($arr[$i]));
        if($level == 1) {
            sort($new);
            if (!in_array($new, $result)) {
                $result[] = $new;          
            }
        } else {
            repeatation($arr, $level - 1, $result, $new);
        }
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
    repeatation($arr, $i+1, $result);
}

foreach ($result as $arr) {
    echo join(" ", $arr) . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Both of you are so good! I wish I could give you both the correct answer!

Comment: @user2318029 you can also upvote if you want

Comment: Believe me I tried.. I need 15 reputation for that.